# The argument type 'Container Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int, int)'. dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am building Flutter App for my Ecommerce Store and integrated with the Rest API (Woo commerce) to fetch the data. I am designing the product details page but now getting an error `itemBuilder`.

I am currently **Flutter Channel dev, 1.27.0-4.0.pre** and developing on **Visual Studio Code**

**I am Facing this error because i think the plugin has updated now and need help now with the update**

Here is the error:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Shahzaib/My_Flutter_Projects/Wahmart_App/wahmart/lib/widgets/widget_product_details.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": {
        "value": "argument_type_not_assignable",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#argument_type_not_assignable",
            "path": "/tools/diagnostic-messages",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev",
            "fragment": "argument_type_not_assignable"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The argument type 'Container Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int, int)'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 32,
    "startColumn": 15,
    "endLineNumber": 32,
    "endColumn": 324,
    "tags": []
}
```

and here is my code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wahmart/models/product.dart';


class ProductDetailsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductDetailsWidget({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);
  Product data;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [productImages(data.images, context)],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productImages(List<Images> images, BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 250,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.network(
                      images[index].src,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                autoPlay: false,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: 1,
                aspectRatio: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[The argument type 'Container Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int, int)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ya0X.png)

Comment: Yes, there's apparently a second int required now in line 32, whatever that is.  Edit: Yeah, I bet it's this... requires two ints: https://pub.dev/documentation/carousel_slider/latest/carousel_slider/ExtendedIndexedWidgetBuilder.html argument to itemBuilder param.

Comment: Thanks for the help...i solved it <3